# Bash script: write CPU utilization to file (Ubuntu)

Tags: bash, ubuntu, cpu

I would like to write a bash script that writes the current CPU utilization to a file "logfile". I am using Intel® Core™ i7-4500U CPU @ 1.80GHz × 4 and Ubuntu 15.10.

I have seen similar questions asked already in this forum, however not all of my questions were answered to 100 percent. By my research I came up with two possible ways of achieving my goal. First one is

```
    mpstat | grep "all" | awk '{ print $3 + $5; }' >> logfile
```

(adding user CPU and system CPU) and my second candidate is

```
   mpstat | grep "all" | awk '{ print 100 - $12; }' >> logfile
```

(100 - %idle CPU). Which one of those two is the right one for me if I am interested in the total CPU utilization (so all components that count in some form as CPU should be included).

Another question: By what I have learned by reading other threads, I think my second candidate

```
   mpstat | grep "all" | awk '{ print 100 - $12; }' >> logfile
```

should be quite accurate. However, when I open the "System Monitor" and monitor the "CPU History" I observe significantly different CPU utilization. Another thing is that the values in the System Monitor are very dynamic (CPU varies between 4% and 18%) whereas over the same period the outcome of the second command remains almost constant. Has someone an explanation for that?

Many thanks for all comments!

Comment: Do you see significantly higher utilization with System Monitor vs. the number returned by this script **at the same time**? Or could it be that the extra CPU usage is merely the System Monitor using more CPU to generate the GUI and plot the usage graphs?

Comment: Yes, I have the System Monitor open and while doing this I hit the second command into the terminal a couple of times. I have just observed that those values can also be (significantly) lower. Another thing is that the values in the System Monitor are very dynamic (CPU varies between 4% and 18%) whereas over the same period the outcome of the second command remains almost constant- I edited this in the post.

Comment: I suggest installing the [GNU accounting utilities](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/acct/).

Comment: This question would probably be more appropriate for unix.stackexchange.com or askubuntu.com. It's not really about scripting, but how the `mpstat` utility works.

Comment: @BJPrim added Bash script to answer that should do what you need (get a more "live" value).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because `mpstat`'s first line shows an average value calculated since the system booted (which will be much more "stable" - will tend to change less and less as time goes by ).

Quote from `mpstat` man page:

> The interval parameter specifies the amount of time in  seconds 
>   between  each  report.   A value  of  0  (or  no  parameters  at  all)
>   indicates that processors statistics are to be reported for the time
>   since system startup (boot).

If you add an interval parameter, you will start to get back live numbers, which should more closely match your System Monitor output (try executing `mpstat 1` vs. the plain `mpstat`).

Therefore, this Bash line should do the trick:

```
mpstat 1 1 | grep "all" | awk '{ print 100 - $NF; exit; }' >> logfile
```

and, to do it without `grep` (saving the extra process spawn):

```
mpstat 1 1 | awk '/all/{ print 100 - $NF; exit; }' >> logfile
```

(changed `$12` to `$NF` for the case when the first line has a time and shifts the arguments over; with `$NF` we consistently get the last value, which is the idle value)

Comment: Wow thank you, such a nice, easy and perfect solution! Now the CPU utilization from mpstat is indeed identical to System Monitor (as far I can tell just by monitoring with my eyes). Thanks a lot!

Comment: @BJPrim Wasn't perfect yet, it still had a `grep` which can be removed :)